# Export news items (including pictures etc.) from Drupal to SQL

Tags: importing-exporting

I would like to export newsitems from Drupal including images to import them into a whole different database.

Is there any module or whats the best way to create an export from Drupal to a SQL, CSV file?

Comment: Are you migrating from Drupal to another system? or you want migrate your Drupal to another database?

Comment: From Drupal to another database. So I would like to export only news items and images belonging to those news items.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export).

> This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into
>   another Drupal installation, or on the same site.
>
> Using this module you can save yourself a lot of time setting up new
>   websites that have similar nodes to websites you've already made,
>   migrating nodes to new Drupal versions, or between
>   development/staging/production sites.
>
> You will need the same content types for the imports to work (unless
>   using Feeds to import), and ideally relevant compatibility with
>   fields, and modules.

**Node export formats**

The format to export with is configurable, and the Node export package comes with the following formats:

> JSON - JavaScript Object Notation code which is known for being
>   security friendly. (Drupal 7 only)
>
> Drupal var export - A Drupalized PHP array which is similar to
>   var_export(). (Drupal 7 only)
>
> Node code - A customized PHP array which is similar to var_export().
>   (Drupal 6 only) CSV - RFC4180 compliant CSV code. Ideal for viewing in
>   Windows software, and editing data as spreadsheets.
>
> Serialize - Very robust, though not human readable, representation
>   through Serialization using the PHP serialize function.
>
> XML - XML 1.0 representation which is good for machine-readability and
>   human-readability.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to export the data for use in an other system, our own CMS. So I'd like to have all elements of the news items to be exported to preferrably SQL

Comment: @tvgemertI don't get how is sql going to help you. Are you planning to have the same table structure, IS so then just go to phpMyAdmin and do an export. CSV is the best option according to me and you will have to write a custom script to do the import into the custom tables which you will create in your own cms.